# Extract information between square brackets for line in text file starting with >

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal

I have many text files which look like this:

```
>CAA97360; SPAC26F1.03 [SCHPO]
M-----FRTCTKIGTVPKVLVNQKGLIDGLRRVTTDATTSRANPAHVPEEHDKPFPVKLD
DSVFEGYKIDVPSTEIEVTKGELLGLYEKMVTIRRLELACDALYKAKKIRGFCHLSIGQE
```

I want to extract the information between the square brackets and retain the M----FRT etc sequence below. So I want the text to look like this:

```
>SCHPO
M-----FRTCTKIGTVPKVLVNQKGLIDGLRRVTTDATTSRANPAHVPEEHDKPFPVKLD
DSVFEGYKIDVPSTEIEVTKGELLGLYEKMVTIRRLELACDALYKAKKIRGFCHLSIGQE
```

How could I do this using the terminal please?

Comment: If it has to be bash scripting, I suggest you look into using AWK. There's a good tutorial here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-scripting-using-awk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With AWK, try something like:

```
gawk '{print gensub(/^>.*\[(.+)\]/, ">\\1", 1)}' text
```

which outputs:

```
>SCHPO
M-----FRTCTKIGTVPKVLVNQKGLIDGLRRVTTDATTSRANPAHVPEEHDKPFPVKLD
DSVFEGYKIDVPSTEIEVTKGELLGLYEKMVTIRRLELACDALYKAKKIRGFCHLSIGQE
```

**Explanations:**

- The `awk` function `gensub()` searches the string (defaulted to `$0`, the current line) for the regular expression (1st argument) and replaces the matched string with the 2nd argument. (Note that this is a very rough overview of `gensub()` function. See the man page for detailed explanations.)
- The regular expression `/^>.*\[(.+)\]/` matches with a line which starts with '>', followed by some characters, and a substring surrounded by square brackets.
  Pay attention to the parens around the the pattern within the square brackets.
- As for the 2nd argument, `\\1` (the leftmost backslash just escapes the next one) indicates the 1st parenthesized expression in the regular expression above.
  It is called a `back reference` and you can reuse the matched substring (the information between the square brackets in this case) with this mechanism.
- If the pattern matches, `gensub()` returns the modified string. Otherwise it returns the original string. So just saying `print gensub() ...` works for both matched and unmatched lines.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much. The explanation was also really helpful

Comment: Good to know I could be helpful to you. I would be appreciated if you can take an action following [the instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). BR.